# CsvHelper library in C#, nulls as empty string

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am trying to use [CsvHelper](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/) library to write records (or `list<SomeModel>`) to CSV, but `SomeModel` class has some reference types properties that are sometimes `null`. I am wondering is there a way to print nulls as empty string instead of  "null". I can see that [`CsvWriter.WriteRecords`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvWriter.cs#L409) method is virtual so I can extend the class and create a custom implementation of it but there should be an easier way or some confirguration.

Comment: @tchelidze What does that mean?

Comment: did you read any of the documentation on the Gethub for CsvHelper under examples it also explains how you can either write out null or use string.Empty http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples

Comment: @MethodMan can you please provide an example on `Map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply set this attribute

```
csv.Configuration.UseNewObjectForNullReferenceMembers = true;
```

it'll simply create a new object if a null reference is found.
In the ctor of the  object class, assign empty string as default.